Restore a PostGRES SQL backup file to an in-memory database in .NET with npgsql
Perhaps I am hallucinating, but I thought older versions of npgsql were able to restore a backup of a postgresql database to an in-memory data store.
However looking at version 8 documentation I cannot find anything that seems to allow this use-case. Has anyone ever done this? I don't really want to fully restore to an online database, since in my usecase, I just need to read values from two tables into CSV and close the file.

Npgsql hasn't supported any such CSV export as far as I'm aware.
But using the PostgreSQL COPY feature, it should be extremely trivial to export a table to CSV, read that with Npgsql and dump it to a file.
